# What layer does the presenter go in?

Tags: layers, mvp

Whereas there seems to be a lot of information on the Internet about what the presenter both is and does, there doesn't seem to be a whole lot that specifically describes where to put it in a multi-layered architecture.  My guess would have been the business layer, but very recently I read something that said the business layer should deal only in domain-/system-wide logic, not anything that's giving commands out to control a specific application's UI.

I'm not too sure what difference there would be between what a business layer deals in and what a controller/presenter deals in, other than that a controller/presenter would somewhat connect business logic with UI logic.

So, for example, if there are separate layers for UI, business, communication, and data access - or if there is any similar setup with a slightly different choice of layers that is ***not*** simply three layers for *model*, *view*, and *controller* themselves - *where would you put a presenter class?*  Would it invariably go in the business layer?  If you do that, do you have to go out of your way to minimize chat between it and the view interface to mitigate overhead from the layering?

Comment: model -> controller / repository -> presenter (prepared data) -> view (UI) Usually presenters are so specific to preparing the data for visualization that they do not involve an overhead. The presenter just wraps the model (or repository) for showing it.

Comment: If you are implementing MVP, it goes (conceptually) in UI layer, as *Controllers* do on MVC patterns. MVP is considered a GUI design pattern Presenters are intended to be a handler of UI events. To operate with the model and to retrieve the UI based on the results of these operations. The problem comes when we tie tightly these operations to business rules. In an ideal scenario (no matter the pattern), the business has nothing to do with UI and it's requirements. Business should be agnostic.

Comment: So the presenter is almost nothing more than a wrapper around the UI that just sort of routes the UI interface's input and output back-and-forth to the rest of the software without worrying about any of the underlying rules or anything?  There would generally be at least one or two full layers between the presenter and the model in that case?  For some reason I was thinking the presenter was more of an overall hub.

Comment: I guess if that's the case, then I understand that the presenter working with the interface abstracts from some of the really specific UI details and just focuses on specific input and output, but creating two additional types for everything (the interface and the presenter) - that sounds just a little intricate if that's all it's really accomplishing.

Comment: Check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056/what-are-mvp-and-mvc-and-what-is-the-difference. I have read it and it summarises well the pattern. It also explains the conceptual differences between MVP and MVC.

Comment: `creating two additional types for everything` -- Before MVP and MVC came along, everyone was writing event-driven, code-behind spaghetti.  The additional type that you refer to isolates the presentation logic from the actual UI surface.  What is this "interface" type that you refer to?

Comment: @RobertHarvey My understanding is that for MVP (probably not for MVC), you have to create an interface around the Windows form or whatever you're working with, and then you have the presenter deal with the interface instead of the class.

Comment: @Panzercrisis: It appears that this interface exists to expose a consistent API to the presenter, regardless of which view is being used.  See http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/70969/implementing-both-poor-mans-mvp-and-mvpvm-framework

Comment: @Laiv Thanks for the link!  Part of the problem I'm having is that different people seem to contradict each other about what the differences are, and a lot of times they're not really describing it in very clear terms. For example, one will say the view talks to the model only in MVC, not in MVP, and another will say it's the other way around or that it's a choice in MVP.  Or one will say it's only one presenter per view, and another might say that's not always the case.

Comment: The one answer seemed pretty good, but I left a comment asking for just a little bit of clarification where they said, "This differs from MVP where actions route through the View to the Presenter. In MVC, every action in the View correlates with a call to a Controller along with an action."

Comment: Take a look to [Vaddin](https://vaadin.com/web/magi/home/-/blogs/model-view-presenter-pattern-with-vaadin) example. And compare it with [Struts 1](https://dzone.com/tutorials/java/struts/struts-tutorial/struts-mvc-architecture-tutorial.html). :-)

Comment: @Laiv If you want to, post a quick answer just saying it goes in the UI layer basically, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My preference is for @Laiv to post an answer, since he/she essentially answered this in the comments, but until then, I'll post this as the answer:

**Presenters go in the UI layer.**